# Removing all rows of JTable bit its footprint remains

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm removing all rows of a `JTable` using this:

```
myTableModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
myTableModel.setRowCount(0);
```

But after deletion its footprint remains! please check this Screenshot:
[image: JTable after deletion]

This only happens when I delete all rows, and if there be even one row there will be bo problem!
Why this happens? how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: don't quite understand what you mean - but: don't use the first line **ever** because it's changing the underlying datastructure under the feet of the model (which may or not lead to not notifying its listeners correctly)

Comment: @kleopatra: I mean the UI is not updating when I delete rows like this! anyway I fixed it by calling `myTable.updateUI();` after deletion; if this method is wrong, how can I clear a `JTable`; I think deleting row by row by `model.removeRow(i)` is inefficient; isn't it?

Comment: Of course it's not updated, how does the model know that you've removed all the data from its internal structure? You should be using removeRow instead

Comment: With your implementation yes. RemoveRow will remove the row from the internal data structure and notify the table of the change, which will update the UI. You should never make assumptions about the assumptions about the internal structure of any model

Comment: Also `updateIU` has nothing to do with repainting or updating the view, but with changing the look and feel

Comment: the second line (only the second!) is exactly what you need to do - if that doesn't work, something is wrong with the code you are not showing - time for an SSCCE

Answer (score 1):

Using a `DefaultTableModel`, the only option you have is to use the functionality provided by the model, `removeRow`

`removeRow` will fire the appropriate events required to tell the `JTable` that it needs to update itself.  The table has been optimised in such away as to improve the painting process

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                    model.addColumn(index);
                }
                for (int row = 0; row < 1000; row++) {
                    String[] values = new String[10];
                    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                        values[col] = row + "x" + col;
                    }
                    model.addRow(values);
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.add(new JButton(new DeleteRowsFromDefaultModel(model)), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class DeleteRowsFromDefaultModel extends AbstractAction {

        private final DefaultTableModel model;

        public DeleteRowsFromDefaultModel(DefaultTableModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            putValue(NAME, "Delete All");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.setRowCount(0);
        }

    }

}
```

If you're really worried about performance, you will need to create your own model and create your own `clear` method that fires the appropriate events.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable1();
    }

    public TestTable1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                MyTabelModel model = new MyTabelModel();
                JTable table = new JTable(model);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.add(new JButton(new DeleteRowsFromMyModel(model)), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DeleteRowsFromMyModel extends AbstractAction {

        private final MyTabelModel model;

        public DeleteRowsFromMyModel(MyTabelModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            putValue(NAME, "Delete All");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.clear();
        }
    }

    public class MyTabelModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<String[]> rows;

        public MyTabelModel() {
            rows = new ArrayList<>(1000);
            for (int row = 0; row < 1000; row++) {
                String[] values = new String[10];
                for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                    values[col] = row + "x" + col;
                }
                rows.add(values);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return String.valueOf(column);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            String[] row = rows.get(rowIndex);
            return row[columnIndex];
        }

        public void clear() {
            int old = getRowCount();
            if (old > 0) {
                rows.clear();
                fireTableRowsDeleted(0, old - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ehh ... no, there's no need whatever for looping in a DefaultTableModel: setRowCount(0) is the method to use. BTW, in the custom model, you wouldn't fire a dataChanged: as you know exactly what happened (deleted all), rowsDeleted would be most appropriate.

Comment: 1- Shows you how often I use `DefaultTableModel` 2- I'm just lazy :P - Corrected (that's right I'm scared of you ;))

Comment: you are far enough away <g>

Comment: @kleopatra That just scares me even more :P